# Bava Metzia question - Shnayim Ochzim

Tags: talmud-gemara, bava-metzia

If three people came into beit din holding a object and two of the people said they both found an object together, and the third person said “I found the object solely by by myself,” what would be done?

What if two people came into beit din holding an object and one person knew an object was half his and half someone else’s (who isn’t there) but the other person holding the object said it’s all his, but person A knows it’s completely not Person C’s at all. Could Person A make the initial claim that it’s all theirs (false) and then swear it’s not less than half theirs (true) so that they get their 50 percent?

Comment: https://mesorahvchidush.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%97%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA/

Comment: To the second question, what if he may do this? He then goes to the true partner and informs him that half was stolen. Whose half was stolen? Does he need to share his half, since he confesses to having a partner but the cheater doesn't? Can Bein Din even rule on such a case, being that it presupposes that their previous ruling was unjust?

Comment: I think this second question is exactly the kind of case where the rule מדבר שקר תרחק applies: You are not allowed to game the rules of beis din, even to get what is rightfully yours. See Maseches Shavuos 30b-31a for many examples of this kind. https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.30b.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: You didn't tell us in the first question how exactly they are holding it. Each a third of the way round or some such? It would matter. If the two were both holding one end, and the third the other end, the question would be easy.